# How to compare two lists and get unmatching items - without using LINQ

Tags: c#, list

I am using 2 lists,

```
List<string> localfiles = new List<string>();

List<string> remotefiles = new List<string>();
```

I need to find all new items in remotefiles  that not present in localfiles. Using LINQ it is easier but I cant use Linq as my application is in .net 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var temp = new List<string>();
foreach(var item in remoteFiles){
  if(localfiles.Contains(item) == false){
     temp.Add(item);
  }
}
```

//temp now contains all items in remoteFiles that are not present in localfiles

Comment: depending on the size of localfiles you 'might' get more performance by creating a dictionary from the list first so the 'look-ups' will be a lot faster (i.e. using .Contains in a list is slower than looking up a key in a dictionary).. but you incurr the additional overhead of creating the dictionary .. so as with everything .. 'it depends' ;-) ... (just like lazyberezovsky is suggesting :-) )

Answer (score 5):

```
Dictionary<string, bool> files = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
foreach (var file in localfiles)
    if (!files.ContainsKey(file))
        files.Add(file, false);

List<string> result = new List<string>();
foreach (var file in remotefiles)
    if (!files.ContainsKey(file))
        result.Add(file);
```

`Dictionary` is more [efficient](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-time) for lookup then `List` if you have more than 3 items in it:

[image]

Comment: `+1` just for spending more effort than OP to solve his problem.

Comment: However, there is a performance penalty from building the dictionary

Comment: @TGH agree, and another penalty is lookup for each item in both lists. So yes, performance will depend on collection sizes